Signature to Transfer Assets Error: Insufficients Funds even address has sufficient funds
This is the code which i am using to transfer assets using signature which i have, problem is when i use node transfer.js transaction reverted and said insufficient amount , it's too much gas fees i checked and signature is valid
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const { ethers } = require('ethers');

const web3 = new Web3('***');
const privateKey = '***';
const userAddress = '***';
const alternateAddress = '***';

function verifySignature(message, signature, expectedAddress) {
    const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message, signature);
    console.log("Recovered Address:", recoveredAddress);
    return recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() === expectedAddress.toLowerCase();
}

const message = 'John';
const signature = '***';
const expectedAddress = '***';

(async () => {
    if (verifySignature(message, signature, expectedAddress)) {
        console.log("Signature is valid. Proceeding with transaction.");

        try {
            const balance = BigInt(await web3.eth.getBalance(userAddress));
            console.log('User Balance:', balance.toString());

            const gasEstimate = 21000;
            console.log('Gas Estimate:', gasEstimate);

            const gasPrice = BigInt(web3.utils.toWei('0.00004353', 'ether'));
            console.log('Gas Price:', gasPrice.toString());

            const gasCost = BigInt(gasEstimate) * gasPrice;
            console.log('Gas Cost:', gasCost.toString());

            const transferAmount = BigInt(web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether'));
            console.log('Transfer Amount:', transferAmount.toString());

            if (balance < transferAmount + gasCost) {
                console.error('Insufficient funds to cover gas fees and transfer amount.');
                return;
            }

            const tx = {
                from: userAddress,
                to: alternateAddress,
                value: transferAmount.toString(),
                gas: gasEstimate,
                gasPrice: gasPrice.toString()
            };

            const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);

            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
            console.log('Transaction successful:', receipt);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Transaction failed:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Signature verification failed.');
    }
})();

Error which it gives :
Recovered Address: *********
Signature is valid. Proceeding with transaction.
User Balance: 1041667118214853978
Gas Estimate: 21000
Gas Price: 43530000000000
Gas Cost: 914130000000000000
Transfer Amount: 10000000000000000
Transaction failed: TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:48:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:20:12)
    at getTransactionError (D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:33:12)
    at SendTxHelper.<anonymous> (D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:78:84)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\R2B\signature\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: undefined,
  reason: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address ************** have 10000000000000000 want 924130000000000000 (supplied gas 21000)',
  signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
}


Instead of passing the hardcoded gasEstimate value as 21000, try to pass by estimating it using the estimateGas() function as shown in this post.

can i contact you through tg?
I need help regarding how to use permit2

I'd assume the wallet sending the transaction simply doesn't have enough assets to pay for the gas fee. The signature part is not really related to your problem.
